# Spark ALS: Running out of java heap space: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib

I am running spark on a single machine, with 24 cores, 48G Ram.

I am able to train an implicit model with 6M users, 1.2M items, 216M actions(views/buy)

Now, I am trying to run recommendations of 7M users and 1.5M items and 440M user actions on items.

I am using 20 executors, driver memory 15G, executor memory 4G.

Training with rank 8, 15 iterations.

I am getting java heap space out of memory error while training the model using ALS.trainImplicit.

```
model = ALS.trainImplicit(training_RDD, rank, seed=seed, iterations=iterations, lambda_=regularization_parameter, alpha=config.alpha)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/mllib/recommendation.py", line 314, in trainImplicit
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/mllib/common.py", line 130, in callMLlibFunc
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/mllib/common.py", line 123, in callJavaFunc
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1133, in __call__
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 319, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o86.trainImplicitALSModel.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 4.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 4.0 (TID 44, localhost, executor driver): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
 at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuilder$ofInt.mkArray(ArrayBuilder.scala:323)
```

I am unable to get how to correct this error. 
from error: **Lost task 0.0 in stage 4.0 (TID 44, localhost, executor driver): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space** ,  I could get that executor is running out of memory.

I have tried increasing executor memory, decreasing driver memory, but it didn't help, I am still getting the same error.

Stack trace of error: https://www.dropbox.com/s/g2vlmtjo8bb4gd1/javaheapspaceerror.txt?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the checkpoint directory :-) A lot of algorithms use this when they are very staging-data intensive, since RDD lineage becomes crazy otherwise and causes these issues.

```
sc.setCheckpointDir('/tmp')
```

Comment: I have set this property, but still I am getting same java heap space error.

Comment: You should try updating the configuration for the job then. The one you stated is physically impossible on your machine (20 executors with 4G = 80G - you only have 48, and this is before including the driver RAM and container overhead). Spark will be just using the config as a guide, and doing the best it can. Why do you need so much driver memory? ALS doesn't use this at all, so I'd consider reducing this. Try 10 executors, each with 2 cores, and 1G RAM, with driver memory 3G. Remember your OS and any other apps need RAM too!

Comment: Hi Ben, Thanks for helping me out here, I tried the recommended configuration but I am still getting the same error. https://www.dropbox.com/s/3ph9etmjl6tylib/javaheapspaceerror_2.txt?dl=0

Comment: Earlier it was 10g, now I have spark.driver.maxResultSize set to 1500m, still getting same error. http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html says, spark.driver.maxResultSize: Setting a proper limit can protect the driver from out-of-memory errors. I am not sure I should set it to low 1500m so that it is less than 2G executor memory or I should set it high(10G) so that intermittent rdds computation don't fail due to low memory error.